# how to enable wallet in a confirmed node

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, bitcoin-cli

I installed/compiled my Bitcoin Core RPC client version v0.16.2.0 and i used --disable-wallet flag.

***I think this is the reason I am seeing "Method not found" errors when trying to GetNewAddress***

how can i install/enable it after having fully confirmed node with up to date blockchain?

os: Ubuntu 16.04.5

**solution**

accepted the answer below but in my case since i set it up sing *apt-install bitcoind* the wallet feature was already there, i just needed to flip the disablewallet=1 flag in my bitcoin.config

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that is a wallet feature. You would have to recompile without the `--disable-wallet` flag, starting back at executing the autotools configure script: `./configure`. See https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-unix.md#disable-wallet-mode.

You also have to make sure you don't set the `-disablewallet` flag when you run `bitcoind` or have it in your `bitcoin.conf` file.

If you need to recompile, you could still back up the data in the `.bitcoin` folder, which includes the blockchain and UTXO set and copy it back over when the installation is complete. That way you don't have to download the blockchain again.

Comment: hmm disablewallet is a setting in my bitcoin.config. after setting it to 0, how do i 'recompile' it ?  there was no strict compilation process when i set it up

Comment: `-disablewallet` is a runtime flag, which is different than the `--disable-wallet` compile flag. So did you compile it or not? Did you run `./configure --disable-wallet` when you first set it up? Instructions to compile are here: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-unix.md

Comment: also not sure what ./configure refers to.. i don't have that dir..

Comment: in installed with *apt-get install bitcoind*

Comment: That is autotools configure script, it scans your machine for dependencies and configures the build process.

Comment: Oh ok, so you didn't compile. Just remove the`disablewallet` line in bitcoin.conf and restart bitcoin `$ bitcoin-cli stop` then `$bitcoind -daemon` and see if it has the wallet functionality.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82142/discussion-between-jbaczuk-and-sonic-soul).